# how can I redirect with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect

When a user clicks a category on the shop-landing page, a sessionStorage var is set and you are redirected to the shop page but the redirect is funky

***OLD CODE (works but breaks on iOS 7.1.1, i think it's a dirty hack.  It redirects to root/shop)

```
.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.sortCategory = function sortCategory(category) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('sortCategory', '.' + category);
        window.location.assign("/shop");
    };
})
```

***NEW CODE (doesn't work, redirects to root/shop-landing#/shop)

```
.controller('myController', function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.sortCategory = function sortCategory(category) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('sortCategory', '.' + category);
        $location.path("/shop");
    };
})
```

The desired url is root/shop.

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: What router are you using? ng-route or ui-router?

Comment: The module is using ngRoute

Comment: Can you share the router code?

Comment: Perhaps the old code breaks because of it's use of 'window' instead '$window'.  Where do i find the router code?

Comment: $window does nothing extra

Comment: From the angular docs - "A reference to the browser's window object. While window is globally available in JavaScript, it causes testability problems, because it is a global variable. In angular we always refer to it through the $window service, so it may be overridden, removed or mocked for testing."

Comment: Perhaps you can try set $locationProvider. `angular.module "APP".config ($locationProvider) -> $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`

Comment: Wrapper, but nothing extra as I said.

Comment: window.location.href = url is the standard way of redirecting to a URL in javascript. The angular $location service deals only with hash routing

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just use `window.location.href = '[enter_url_here]'`?

This is pretty standard for redirecting a user with JavaScript.

Comment: I was just about to answer with Alex Hills suggestion.  This gives me the required URL, but have to wait until it is tested on an iOS 7.1.1 device to see if it fixed the bug 'window.location.assign()' was causing.

Comment: Buttons still unresponsive on iOS 7.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilities. The first one is to use the mentioned property:

```
window.location.href = '/shop';
```

or the [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) service

```
$location.path('/shop');
```

Here on [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ICrzfI7689x0gjKJnJUp?p=preview) is a working example. And probably you may use the absolute navigation in your path like this:

```
window.location.href = '../shop';
```